# Powershell On Windows Server 2008 vs. Windows XP?

Tags: powershell, syntax-error

I'm writing a PowerShell script for a particular client. I tested the script on several of our desktop machines, and the tried the script on the client's system. I ran into the following issues:

#### Issue #1

As a good little Do Bee, I defined a bunch of help text, so when you run `Get-Help` on my script, it would give you detailed help. I used the following syntax:

```
<#
Get-Help

.SYNOPSIS
  C> FileWatcher.ps1 -FilePath <FileName> -SenderEmail Bob@Foo.com ^
    -ToEmail Joe@Bar.com -SmtpServer smtp.foo.com

.DESCRIPTION
Blah, blah, blah...
#>
```

On my machine, it works, and this is recognized as comment. However, on the client's machine, this produced an error as soon as it saw the `C>` which it thought was a redirect. Getting rid of the `#>` and `<#` and putting `#` in front of each line got rid of this problem, and brought us Issue #2.

#### Issue #2

I defined a bunch of parameters like this:

```
Param (
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType 'Leaf'})]
    [Parameter(
        Position=0,
        HelpMessage="File you want to watch")]
        $FilePath = "\\rke032\QuickCon\wincommlog.000",

    [String]
    [Parameter(
    blah, blah, blah
```

PowerShell coughed on `[ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType 'Leaf'})]` saying it wasn't a valid type.

As I said, we tested this on a wide variety of Windows machines. I have a Windows XP machine. It's PowerShell version # 6.0.6002.1811. On another machine that's running Windows 7, the PowerShell version is 6.1.7600.

On the client's machine (a Windows 2008 Server) which is giving us these errors, the version is 6.0.6001.18000.

We ran the Powershell scripts by bringing up a PowerShell window, and then typing in the script's name. The ExecutionPolicy is set to Unrestricted.  The script has a *.ps1 suffix on the end. I can't believe there's that big a difference between revision 6.0.6002 and 6.0.6001 to have a problem with unrecognized syntax. Is there something else going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the output of `$PSVersionTable` and not the build version. In particular the `PSVersion` property is interesting. I guess you have PS1 on one machine and PS2 on another. The extension is `.ps1` regardless of the PowerShell version.

This guess is reinforced by noticing that block comments don't work and neither do parameter attributes.

Comment: Thanks. Will look at the `$PSVersionTable` on that system and see if this is an issue.

Comment: Looked for that $PSVersionTable variable. It wasn't there. Further Googling reveal that the $PSVersionTable variable itself was a PowerShell V2 feature. This is a Windows 2007 machine, and PSV2 wasn't introduced until Windows 2007 R2. Dammit. We used PowerShell because we though it would be easier than trying to get the customer to install Python or Perl. Now, after two weeks of work and testing, we're pretty much back to square 1. This sucks so much it blows. Thx for your help. I'll have to see if we have PS1 documentation and a test machine with PS1 on it.

Comment: Erm, you can just install PowerShell v2 on any machine with XP SP2 and later. This includes Server 2008. It just isn't installed by default (like it is on Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7).

Comment: This isn't **our** machine. It's a customer's production system. Otherwise, I would have installed Python or Perl that our developers know and be done with it. We aren't allowed to change anything on these servers. It took a week just to change the server's ExecutionPolicy to allow us to run the PowerShell script.